# Co-occurrence matrix factorization ALS

Tags: regression, optimization, matrix, recommender-system, cooccurrence

Let's say I have an item-item co-occurrence matrix that I want to factorize. I'll thus only have item factors. Is it possible to learn the factors using ALS ?
I can't see how given that we'd have to fix the very vectors we want to update ... perhaps there is a workaround.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.